# MomentJS + VueJS: Getting Relative Time From Now To A Certain Point In The Past

Tags: vue.js, momentjs

I use MomentJS.

in my VueJS-Code I want to get the relative time from now to that point in the past. In my template I incorporate the result of this short piece of JavaScript:

```
<template>
  <div>{{ moment(message.createdAt, 'YYYYMMDD').fromNow() }}</div>
</template>
```

the object receives the date as follows:

```
message: { createdAt: Date.now() }
```

the result is always: `a few seconds ago` ...

how can I get the correct result (not always "a few seconds ago"):

**EDIT:**

this is my full template:

```
<template v-for="message in messages">
  <div class="message">
    <div class="text">{{ message.text }}</div>
    <div class="date">{{ moment(message.createdAt).format('D.M.YYYY') }}</div>
    <div class="date">{{ moment(message.createdAt).fromNow() }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can't use moment directly in your template, as it's not white-boxed (not accessible in the template).

> Template expressions are sandboxed and only have access to a whitelist of globals such as Math and Date. You should not attempt to access user defined globals in template expressions.

Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions

I would advise you to use some filter instead (you can also do it with methods in a very similar way).

Here is a working example.

```js
  
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data() {
        return {
            messages: [
                {
                    text: 'Message1',
                    createdAt: new Date() // Now
                },
                {
                    text: 'Message2',
                    createdAt: new Date(2016, 3, 1) // 1 April 2017
                }
            ],
            interval: null
        };
    },
    filters: {
        format(date) {
            return moment(date).format('D.M.YYYY')
        },
        fromNow(date) {
            return moment(date).fromNow();
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.$forceUpdate(), 1000);
        // Trigger an update at least each second
        // You should probably raise this duration as refreshing so often
        // may be not useful 
    },
    beforeDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.js"></script>
<div id="app">

    <template v-for="message in messages">
      <div class="message">
        <div class="text">{{ message.text }}</div>
        <div class="date">{{ message.createdAt | format }}</div>
        <div class="date">{{ message.createdAt | fromNow }}</div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much, but if time changes do the values in the template also change ???

Comment: I am not used to Filters ... :D so thank you for expanding my brain!

Comment: so yes I understand, but what about time changes ??

Comment: No, you'r right, they will not change except if you make the template re-render. What about making an interval to trigger that?

Comment: I'll add a tip.

Comment: YOU DID IT !! :D thank you so much. I learned a lot! Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Cobaltway's reply is working, but I would advise to extract the whole logic into a small component of its own, so you don't  force Vue to re-render the whole component each time.

I created exactly this as an example a while ago, please see this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/Linusborg/meovg84x/

```js
Vue.component('dynamic-from-now',{
    name:'DynamicFromNow',
  props: {
    tag: {type: String, default: 'span'},
    value: {type: String, default: ()=> moment().toISOString() },
    interval: {type: Number, default: 1000}
  },
  data() {
    return { fromNow: moment(this.value).fromNow() }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.updateFromNow, this.interval)
    this.$watch('value', this.updateFromNow)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId)
  },
  methods: {
    updateFromNow() {
        var newFromNow = moment(this.value).fromNow(this.dropFixes)
      if (newFromNow !== this.fromNow) {
        this.fromNow = newFromNow
      }
    }
  },
  render(h) {
    return h(this.tag, this.fromNow)
  }
})
```

Usage:

```
<dynamic-from-now :value="yourTimeStamp" :interval="2000" :tag="span" class="red" />
```

Comment: this probably could be improved further by using one shared setInterval, but I hope you get the gist of the idea.

Comment: thank you LINUS. another thing: where should I place authentication logic in my VueJS-project?

Comment: I think that should be a new topic ;)